# XPS 9550 Bluetooth Firmware Load Failed

Tags: drivers, 18.04, bluetooth, broadcom, firmware

I'm wondering if someone can explain *why* this happened -- I've already figured out the fix, but I'm still curious.

I tried to pair my MX Master with my Dell 9550 and it failed. When I ran `grep -i blue /var/log/syslog` I saw `[140171.203358] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd failed with error -2`.

I downloaded the firmware from https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware (I had to rename the file) and moved it in to /lib/firmware/brcm and after rebooting, everything works.

What I don't understand is *why* was the file missing? I would have expected Ubuntu to have included it it with the distribution or the bluetooth package.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to rename it

```
sudo cp /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM20703A1-0a5c-6410.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
```

Shutdown and boot

Answer (score 0):

Remember to adjust a friend's bluetooth.

```
wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/blob/master/brcm/BCM20703A1-0a5c-6410.hcd
sudo cp BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/
sudo chmod 0644 /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM-0a5c-6410.hcd
sudo reboot
```

It's the same thing you wanted to do, but remember to give them the permissions.