# Bluetooth dell xps 9550

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I've a little problem with my Bluetooth adapter.

BCM20703 Bluetooth 4.1

I tried on debian first and now I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. The Bluetooth got detected and connect to the devices but... it keep constantly lose the connection.
I've tried with this [Dell XPS 15 9550 - Bluetooth is not Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401055/dell-xps-15-9550-bluetooth-is-not-working) and this [XPS 9550 Bluetooth Firmware Load Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1093466/xps-9550-bluetooth-firmware-load-failed) .

No luck, if I use those fixes the Bluetooth not power on anymore and say `firmware: failed to load brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob (-2)`

Any idea?
Thanks guys.

Output when i use the fixes:

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i blue

[ 7.829519] usb 1-4: Product: BCM920703 Bluetooth 4.1
[ 26.510579] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[ 26.510599] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 26.510602] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 26.510604] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 26.510607] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 26.622929] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 26.622931] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 26.622934] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 28.654778] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[ 36.882694] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)


sudo dmesg | grep -i firmware

[ 0.082797] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[ 0.285122] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[ 7.245477] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin
[ 7.245762] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_27.bin (v1.27)
[ 25.955065] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db
[ 25.976270] platform regulatory.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware regulatory.db.p7s
[ 26.166382] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.bin
[ 26.166579] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Dell Inc.-XPS 15 9550.txt (-2)
[ 26.167992] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.Dell Inc.-XPS 15 9550.txt failed with error -2
[ 26.168019] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt (-2)
[ 26.168021] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.txt failed with error -2
[ 26.689173] brcmfmac 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load brcm/brcmfmac43602-pcie.clm_blob (-2)
[ 26.689619] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43602/1 wl0: Nov 10 2015 06:38:10 version 7.35.177.61 (r598657) FWID 01-ea662a8c

sudo lspci 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation HM170/QM170 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM170 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43602 802.11ac Wireless LAN SoC (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
06:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
07:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
07:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
07:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation DSL6340 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Alpine Ridge 2C 2015]
3e:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation DSL6340 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]

sudo lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 04f3:21d5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:6410 Broadcom Corp. BCM20703A1 Bluetooth 4.1 + LE
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 258a:0001 SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Edit: official firmware from vendor now load but... same issue as before.... it have a low range like 1 Mt and keep blocking during the stream.

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: And also output of `lsusb` command.

Comment: The problem is with this `Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout`. All other firmware messages are unrelated to BT.

Comment: So? Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Where is `lsusb` output?

Comment: added into the post

Comment: No, you didn't.

Comment: Oh. so sorry ahah. I've confused lspci with lsusb. Added for real now.

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows

Comment: Yes, and on it it work well.

Comment: Disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: It's already off

Comment: I am running out of ideas. Turn the comp off completely and boot into Ubuntu. Check dmesg if it tries to load BT firmware. Now it doesn't.

Comment: It always say direct firmware failed to load

Comment: Which firmware fail to load?  You mix up Wi-Fi and BT firmware.

Comment: Same output as before, wifi always work.